# Dynamic SQL-Application

Tags: java, sql

I want to create a dynamic sql java application. Normaly i create a java pojo with hard coded columns. For Example:

```
public class DbEntry{

private int id;
private String name;

public setter and getter

}
```

Now, the problem is, that the user can change the Database columns as he need. For example, he can add new columns if he need and so on. But if he change the columns the hard coded pojo cant representate the whole db entry. I have read over dynamic byte code creation, but i dont really want to use this, if there is an other/better solution.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do with the application?  Is it a schema viewer?

Comment: No it should store some data like serial numbers, names, company and so on.

Comment: Buf it the user can change the entire table how do you know what logic to associate to each column?  There is nothing set in stone here.

Comment: Yes, that is the problem. For example: I am the user of the application and can store name, company and serial. Now i want also store the date on which the entry was created. I have to call the programmer to change the code, so that i can store this information too. My plan is to enable the user, to add via the application this column and also us it in the application without code it again. I´m already using some program like this, its called WinFiler. Its a really old program but there i have the opportunity to add and delete fields for data store.

Comment: But how are you using this data?  If it is just for viewing, you can just use a spreadsheet.  Maybe even google docs spreadsheets. If you need to control the data and capture historical data etc, just use extension tables and deploy new known attributes each release.  As @EdH points out, it's a lot of work to let them do whatever whenever they feel like, developers really don't want to go there if they absolutely don't have to.  Trust me, I wouldn't.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider this class:

```
public class DbEntry{
  List<Integer> integerList;
  List<String> strList;
  public Integer getInt(int index){
    return integerList.get(index);
  }
  public String getStr(int index){
    return strList.get(index);
  }
  //todo: add some constructors/factory methods
}
```

For fixed columns, you can write some global constants like `staic int I_ID=0` and `static int I_NAME=0`. So you can get the `id` and `name` of an `DbEntry` by calling `dbEntry.getInt(I_ID)` and `dbEntry.getStr(I_NAME)`

For changeable columns you can use a `List<String>`, add new column names to the list and then you can call `dbEntry.getStr(collst.indexOf("name"))`

Or you can write a class using strings as keys, so you can call `dbEntry.getStr("name")`, e.g.:

```
public class DbEntry{
  Map<String,Integer> integerMap;
  Map<String,String> strMap;
  public Integer getInt(String key){
    return integerMap.get(key);
  }
  public String getStr(String key){
    return strMap.get(key);
  }
  //todo: add some constructors/factory methods
}
```

This class looks more straightforward but it wastes some memory. Because every `dbEntry` in the same table has the same set of column names. A single list is enough for storing the column names of a table. `HashMap` uses more memory than `ArrayList`. Despite this disadvantage, what data structures to use still depends on your requirements.

Or you may want to make it an interface with `getInt`, `getStr`, `getDate`, `getBlob`, so you can have the flexibility by implementing the interface using different data structures.

Answer (score 0):

I have seen this done, and it is a lot of work.  What you end up doing is having a dynamic model, typically modelling classes and attributes.  You expose the Classes and Attributes (and their definition) to a sysadmin role.

The rest of the application sends and retrieves instance data using this dynamic model.  As a start, you won't have static Java classes representing them.  In your above example, the DbEntry doesn't exist.  You'll end up with a generic Model Object that allows you to return DbEntry objects in a common model.  Something like

```
class DynamicObject {
    ClassDefinition getClass(); // a ClassDefinition that contains details about DbEntry
    Collection<AttributeDetails> getAttributes();
    AttributeValue getValue(AttributeDetails details);
    void setValue(AttributeDetails details, AttributeValue value);
}
```

This above is all bespoke code written/defined by you.  I am unaware of any third party framework that provides this to you.  That said, I haven't looked very hard.

The bottom line is, for what you want to do, the Classes and Attributes end up being modelled by the application and the rest of the application works off that model.  Only by doing that, will you prevent the need for making static Java changes when the model changes.

It is not trivial, and carries with it a fair amount of maintenance.  I have seen this done, and over time it did become a fairly arduous task to maintain.

Comment: I guess I should also state that your server processes would need to dynamically build out the SQL that ends up being run, based on the contents of the attributes and their values for the object being passed in.  Again, not insignificant work here.

Comment: There are certain frameworks that generate SQL dynamically for you. Hibernate is one of them.

Comment: I guess my experience with Hibernate is that there is still a static definition of an entity: either via Annotations or a hbm.xml file.  The end result is still changing code (via a developer) in order to make model changes.  That said, if hibernate has a way of dynamically (programmatically) defining the structure of the model, I'm just not aware of it.  My experience with hibernate is probably what I could consider mainstream.  But if it exists, you still have to update your application to maintain this model.

Comment: Looks like there is some support for that: https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/core.old/reference/en/html/persistent-classes-dynamicmodels.html  You lose the compile-time checking you get with statically defined classes.  Then again, most anything supporting a dynamically-defined model will lose compile-time checking. As there's nothing to compile.